# Referencing a child component inside v-dialog

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem to get the reference of a component inside the component *v-dialog* of vuetify.

This code prints *undefined* in console instead of the object.

```
<template>
    <v-dialog ref="mydialog">
        <v-card ref="mycard">
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
      console.log(this.$refs.mycard);
  }
}
</script>
```

Is not possible to access a child component by reference inside a *v-dialog* ?

Comment: How about `console.log(this.$refs.mydialog);` ? what will it print?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get access to v-card component because of lazy loading in vuetify 2.

If you are sure that you need to access the v-card component at mounted stage, you could add **eager** prop to v-dialog component.

This code works:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog ref="mydialog" eager>
    <v-card ref="mycard">
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log(this.$refs.mycard);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a better solution than eager load everything? Some king of `MountedAndLoaded()` lifecycle method?

Comment: @wondra, I don't think so. Probably it could be done using some custom event handling, but it very much depends on what kind of problem you are solving. You could take a look at [vue lifecycle diagram](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), but I don't think it will help in any way because it's just a vuetify restriction.

Answer (score 0):

because the dialog isn't shown, set value prop as true and you can get your reference

```
<template>
    <v-dialog ref="mydialog" :value="true">
        <v-card ref="mycard">
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
      console.log(this.$refs.mycard);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! this works too but with @dreamwalker solution is not required to show the dialog